# Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to implement a send mail code but I'm getting the following error :

```
Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior
```

Here is my code piece:

```
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mail.setToRecipients(["@gmail.com"])            
        presentViewController(mail, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        // show failure alert
    }
```

Comment: Where did you placed this code ?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention. It's called from action of a button. And class definition as below class SettingsViewController: UITableViewController ,MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate

Comment: This is not the full error ! Check again please ! Should be saying like UIAlertController ! Or something ?

Comment: Its (<UIAlertController: 0x7fc3b50c6aa0>) . But there is no defined alert controller in my source code.

Comment: Sorry, where did you mention?

Comment: are you presenting UIAlertController or uialertview or action sheet before presenting the mail ? Or just a button and then it should show the mail directly ?

Comment: There is a button at tableview controller and it will directly send mail

Comment: Last thing , So the warning shows when you click on the button or when your settings view controller loads ?

Comment: Apologies,I should give more details. By the way warning has shown when buton clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error that you received could happen if you forgot to remove the segue to another function of your button.

Answer (score 1):

I think your "mail" object is going out of scope and getting deallocated before it is presented.

Try making "mail" a class-level var at the top of your view controller:

```
    var mail: MFMailComposeViewController?
```

Then set and use it in your button action:

```
    self.mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mail!.mailComposeDelegate = self
    //etc....
```

EDIT: The mail object is retained by the presentViewController function, so my answer is incorrect. Thanks to Daniel Zhang for pointing this out.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the early release of the locally defined `MFMailComposeViewController` that is passed to `presentViewController:animated:completion:` is not the issue as it is retained until the view controller is dismissed. I believe there is other code that is not shown that is causing the problem.

Comment: @DanielZhang after some testing here I would agree with you. I could not repro the error.

Comment: @DanielZhang You're quite right. I just realized that I forgot to remove segue to other function of that button. If you write it as answer, I will mark it.

Comment: @batgun I went through and tested all of the cases that you presented along with all of the other hypotheses that were contributed and that's how I came to that conclusion. Glad you got it fixed.